# If $\int_1^\infty x^{-p} dx\,$ exists, then does $\int_1^\infty x^{-q} dx\,$ exist, where $q > p$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

If $\int_1^\infty x^{-p} dx\,$ exists, then does $\int_1^\infty x^{-q} dx\,$ exist, where $q > p$?

My initial assumption is that the answer was true. Because if p is an arbitrary number 5, then the area is $1/4$. So then q could be 2, giving 1 for an area.

These values for p and q both make the integral exist, however what if you use 1 for q. The answer is $\infty$, which is divergent, so it does not exist.

Since no values are given for p and q, how do I know whether the improper integral exists or not?

Comment: Yes, a version of comparison.

Comment: What andre?....

Comment: In fact, we have for $p>1$,$$\int_1^\infty x^{-p}\,dx=\frac{1}{p-1}$$

Comment: @Dr.MV, I'm not sure how this helps. Can you elaborate?

Comment: You are correct, that we require $p>1$ for convergence; else the integral diverges.

Comment: But what if p is 1.01 and q is 1.001. q > p (because they are both negative) and neither diverge. But you could use p is 1.01 and q is 1. Then the second formula doesn't exist because it diverges. So how do I know what values of p and q we are talking about?

Comment: We can say that if $q>p$ and that the integral with integrand $x^{-p}$ converges, then the integral with integrand $x^{-q}$ also converges.   That does not imply that for $p'<p$, the integral with integrand $x^{-p'}$ diverges.  Clearly, if $p'>1$ then the integral with $x^{p'}$ converges.

Answer (score 1):

To show that $\int_1^\infty x^{-q}\,dx$ exists, we need to show that
$$\lim_{B\to\infty}\int_1^B x^{-q}\,dx$$
exists. We are told that $\int_1^\infty x^{-p}\,dx$ exists. In particular, this implies that $p$ is positive.

We are also told that $p\lt q$. From this it follows that $x^{-q}\le x^{-p}$ for all $x\ge 1$, and therefore 
$$f(B)=\int_1^Bx^{-q}\,dx\le \int_1^\infty x^{-p}\,dx$$
for all $B$. Since the function $f(B)$ is increasing and bounded above, $\lim_{B\to\infty} f(B)$ exists, and therefore our improper integral exists.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: If $q>p $ and $|x|\geq 1$ then $|x|^q\geq |x|^p$. So  $\frac{1}{|x|^p}\geq\frac{1}{|x|^q}$.

Comment: Here, $x\ge 1$.

Comment: I wrote wrong, thanks.